# Extracting timestamp from string with regex in Spark RDD

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I have a log like :

```
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
20:33:05 0
[Pipeline] echo
```

I am trying to only extract the `time` information here (20:33:05).

I have tried to do the following:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/logs/log7.txt")  
val individualLines=lines.flatMap(_.split("\n")) //Splitting file contentinto individual lines
val dates=individualLines.filter(value=>value.startsWith("[0-9]"))
```

I am getting the output as

```
MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at DateExtract.scala:30
```

How should the regex be defined here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a log files with the data in new line you do not have to `split` it, you can simply read each line is a `String` data

Then check if it starts with digit by `Character.isDigit` this function as below

```
  val lines = sc.textFile("/logs/log7.txt")
  val dates=lines.filter(value=>Character.isDigit(value.charAt(0)))
            .map(_.split(" ")(0))
  dates.foreach(println)
```

If you want to strictly match the timestamp with regex and filter unmatched then you can use

```
val dates=lines.filter(value=>Character.isDigit(value.charAt(0)))
    .map(_.split(" ")(0))
    .filter(_.matches("""\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"""))
```

Output:

```
20:33:05
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to get only the time, not along with the '0'

Comment: Oh, Thankyou @RameshMaharjan dai :)

Comment: great answer :)

Comment: The second one seems to be a nice add-on!!

Comment: Yeah the second one the better